# Bonus Spell Explanation with Empower Spell Feat 3.5e

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats, bard

I'm very new to the spellcaster archetype in D&D. I've been playing rogues exclusively in 3e and 5e in every one of my campaigns, so yeah.

I'm playing a level 3 bard with 17 charisma. I only know level 0 and 1 spells.

In terms of bonus spells, with the feat empower spell, can I cast an empowered level 0 using a level 2 slot, since my character has a bonus level 2 spell slot and empower increases the spell level by 2?

Comment: I'm playing 3.5e, sorry i forgot to mention the version

Comment: 3e or 3.5e? They can be very different.

Comment: yep, it's the correct version

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Welcome indeed! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you're welcome to join us in [chat].

Comment: Hey, I’m pretty sure we already have an answer to this question, so I’ve linked this one to that one. If for some reason I’ve misunderstood and they’re different questions, it might help to clarify your question and then we can re-open.

Comment: The link does not provide a clear answer to my question. I'm asking if I can cast a level 0 as a level 2 with the empower spell feat since i have the bonus slot for it.

edit: in the SRD, it is said that only the effect is augumented, not the saving throw.

http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#empowerSpell

Comment: The linked question *is* the same as yours, but approaching it from a different angle. *In terms of bonus spells, with the feat Empower Spell, can I cast an empowered level 0 [spell] using a level 2 slot, since my character has a bonus level 2 spell slot and empower increases the spell level by 2?* is what you asked, but the Empower Spell feat isn't important; what *is* important is that the character *can't* use bonus slots from a high ability score until a class allows the character to cast spells of that level (i.e. has a 0 or more not a — in the class's spells for that level).